# Do questions referencing the blog create trackbacks?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, blog

This probably should go in meta, but I just wanted to see if this works. Moderator can delete this later.

If I post a question about [a post in the GIS stackexchange blog](http://gis.blogoverflow.com/2011/09/maperitive-tutorial-generating-osm-map-for-adobe-illustrator-in-seven-easy-steps/), does it generate a [trackback](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trackback) on that blog post?

Answer (score 2):

Joel Spolsky [said](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000007.html) ...

> If it's a core business function -- do it yourself, no matter what.

Therefore, **SE should write its own blogging software instead of relying on Wordpress.**

[image]

SE's core is where the asterisk is.  Unfortunately, without things like trackbacks and blog identity management, this is just another pretty diagram.

Comment: trackbacks have been dead a very, very long time... http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/12/the-day-the-trackbacks-died.html

Comment: @Jeff SE should [roll their own blog software](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/614/should-se-roll-their-own-blogging-software) to prevent trackback abuse.

Answer (score 1):

It did not for one my blog posts on the stats site (see the [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/13858/1036) and therein referenced blog post). Also since the blog(s) are hosted on wordpress, there does not appear to be perfect referencing between the systems (not sure if that would impede the generation of a trackback). See this [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/97950/150339) on SO.META and the ensuing discussion about how badges for blog posts would (likely) not be possible.

Also check to make sure trackbacks aren't getting caught in the wordpress spam folder (if that is you don't mind them to be posted).